# Request failure with django API and Alamofire

Tags: django, swift3, django-rest-framework, alamofire

Requests with Alamofire 4 in Swift 3 always fails with 500 status code. I tryed in Postman and works!

Look at my code:

```
func newUser(user: User) {

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url + "/register")!)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"

    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "username": "\(user.name!)",
        "email": "\(user.email!)",
        "password": "(Kh=CE)4r)PC4}f?",
        "profile": [
            "status": 0,
            "level": 0,
            "facebook_id": "\(user.fbId!)",
            "facebook_token": "000",
            "push_device_token": "000",
            "photo": "\(user.photoUrl!)"
        ]
    ]

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type": "application/json"]

    Alamofire.request(url+"/register", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding(options: []), headers: headers).response { response in
        debugPrint(response)
        print(response)
    }

}
```

[image]

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same thing you are trying to accomplish and the only difference I see is your header, try changing it to:

```
 let headers = ["Authorization": )", password]
```

Wireshark can also help you to see the exact reason for the 500 error.